# Selectively Log PHP Output to a log file instead printing it to the browser

Tags: php, linux, logging, command-line, cron

I have a cron job that runs every 8 minutes:

```
*/8 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/xxx/public_html/ooo.php >> /home/xxx/ooo.log
```

Currently it outputs some sensitive information if I were to goto this in my browser. Is there a way to not output it to the browser and only have it show up in the log file?

I just use alot of print_r() functions. Or is there a special function that can do what I need?

Comment: [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) is the default function used to log errors (though you don't *have* to log errors only, depending on the parameters you pass you can log pretty much anything). Another, more practical option is to use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog).